# Retrieve a list of all Google Plus Contacts that have an application installed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api-ruby-client

I have a big problem with retrieving a list of Google Plus Contact that have installed my application. I tried to use this [gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client), that is recommended in Google Places API Documentation, but it was a fail :(.

I tried this:

```
require 'google/apis/people_v1'
People = Google::Apis::PeopleV1
people = People::PeopleService.new
people.authorization = { client_id: Figaro.env.gci, client_secret: Figaro.env.gcs, access_token: current_user.google_access_token }
```

This worked with no errors, but now I have no idea hot to get People list...

This things are happening on server-side(API) and Google Plus login is happening on client side.

Can someone help me to understand how to do this?